# Capturing video on iOS device?

Tags: ios, video

How can I capture a video on an iOS device or the iOS emulator?

I saw some product pages that are using videos demonstrating that how their apps to be used. The video is also showing the touch and other gestures of the user. How can I create such video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it in the Emulator, you can just use Quicktime, since the latest version supports Screen Recording. Keep in mind though that it captures the entire screen and not just a particular window.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there a solution that would also capture my touches somehow